# Solving differential equations that have a solution non-differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, continuity

I found a problem in my textbook that seemed easy at first. It was about finding the solutions to the differential equation $(f^2(x))'=f(x)$. However we only know that $f^2$ is differentiable, not necesarily $f$ and the problem showed solutions that are non-differentiable functions. Is there a way to solve such problems, where an expresion of a function is differentiable, but not the function itself?

The problem is:

Find all the functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ knowing that $f^2$ differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and $(f^2)'=f$. (here $f^2$ means $f$ times $f$ and not $f \circ f$ and $g'$ is the derivative of the function $g$)

Proof: 
It's obvious that $f(x)=0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ verifies the requirments.
Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a function such that $\exists x_0 \in \mathbb{R}, f(x) \neq 0$. Since the derivative of $f^2$ exists, $f^2$ is continuous and there is a neighbourhood $V$ of $x_0$ where $f^2>0$. We will be making the following notations:
$$a=\inf \{t \in (-\infty, x_0) : f^2(x)>0, \forall x \in [t, x_0] \}$$
$$b=\sup \{t \in (x_0, +\infty) : f^2(x)>0, \forall x \in [x_0, t] \}$$
We have that $-\infty \le a < x_0 < b \le +\infty$ and $f(x) \neq 0, \forall x \in (a, b)$. Since $f=(f^2)'$, the function $f$ has the Darboux property(intermediate value property). This comes from Darboux's theorem. Therefore $f(x)$ has the same sign on $(a, b)$, that is $f(x) > 0$ or $f(x) < 0,$ $\forall x \in (a, b)$. 
Suppose $f(x)>0, \forall x \in (a, b)$. 
 Then $f = \sqrt{f^2}$, so $f$ is differentiable on $(a, b)$. Thus $2f(x)f'(x)=f(x), \forall x \in (a, b) \implies f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}, \forall x \in (a, b)$. We conclude that $\exists c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}+c, x \in (a, b)$. Because $f(x)>0, f(a)>0 \implies a \ge -2c \implies a$ is finite. From the definition of a and the continuity of $f^2$ we can see that $f^2(a)=0$, therefore $c=-\frac{a}{2}$ and $f(x)=\frac{x-a}{2}, x \in [a, b)$ If $b$ would be finite, we would get $0=f^2(b)=\lim_{x \to b^+}(\frac{x-a}{2})^2=\frac{(b-a)^2}{4} \neq 0$, therefore a contradiction so $b=+\infty$ and $f(x)=\frac{x-a}{2}, x \in [a, \infty)$. Moreover $f(x) \le 0, \forall x \in (-\infty, a)$ (the textbook did not gave any explanation, but I could prove it by contradiction.) 
Now suppose $f(x)<0, \forall x \in (a, b)$. Analogously, we get that $b$ is finite and $f(x)=\frac{x-b}{2}, x \in (-\infty, b]$ and $f(x) \le 0, x \in (b, +\infty)$. 
Among $f(x)=0$ the textbook gives 4 more other types of functions: 
[image]

I don't get how they came up type 3, but the rest of the proof is clear. I would also like to know if there is a way to find solution to differential equations that are not differentiable functions. For example type, from the image, type 1, 2, 3 are not differentiable in a finite number of points. However these type of functions do not arrise from solving the differential equation $(f^2(x))'=f(x) \implies f(x)(2f'(x)-1)=0 \implies f(x)=k$ or $f(x)=0.5x+c$. I think this is because we assume, in the first place, that $f(x)$ is differentiable. Is there a way to generalize an algorithm to solve differential equations knowing the function itself is not differentiable but another function g(f(x)) is differentiable? Like we are given that g(f(x)) is differentiable and the differential equation is given in terms of g.

Comment: Actually, those solutions **do** arise from solving the equation by considering $(f\cdot{f})'=2ff'.$ The issue you are not considering is that the equation $f(2f'-1)=0$ does not imply $f=0$ or $f'=1/2$ like you said it does. It actually has a broader range of implications. What it does imply is that for some open set $S,$ $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in{S},$ and $f(x)=x/2+k$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}-S.$ This actually covers all four of the piecewise cases in your answer, and infinitely many more other cases not covered by your answer.

Comment: Also, there is one thing I should clarify: if $f\cdot{f}$ is differentiable, then $f$ has to be differentiable, unless $f$ is some kind of function that is related to the Dirichlet function, but in that case, you can clearly see that there is no $f$ such that the equation is satisfied. If you investigate this from using the definiton of differentiability, you can see this has to be the case. That is why the approach actually worked in this case. As for the actual question, I am a bit confused. A differential equation must involve differentiable functions.

Comment: A differential equation can never have non-differentiable solutions: they must be differentiable on some non-empty open interval, at least. Otherwise, it is not a differential equation, at least not in terms of that function. I think in this case, though, you are asking about a genuine differential equation, and you just worded it poorly. You are asking, in general, about equations of the form $(g\circ{f})'=f,$ where obviously, $g\circ{f}$ is differentiable, but furthermore, $g$ itself is differentiable, and $f$ is not known to be differentiable.

Comment: @Angel yes that is what I meant was $(g \circ f)'=f$, where it is only known if that $g \circ f$ is differentiable. About the fact that if $f \cdot f$ is differentiable then $f$ is differentiable. Can't we take $f(x)=\begin{cases}x & x \neq 3\\ -3 & x = 3 \\ \end{cases}$? Wouldn't $f \cdot f=x^2$? Also why if $f(2f'-1)=0$ implies that $f(x)=0$ on an open set. Why necesarily open. Sorry if I am asking obvious questions, but I have just started learning about real analysis.

Comment: In your example, $f$ is differentiable everywhere except at $-3,$ so that fits what I was saying. The reason $S$ has to be an open set is because the concept of differentiation is not even defined for functions whose domain is not an open set. This is because the derivative is defined in terms of limits.